# Calculus Rate of Change in Triangles

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The base of an isosceles triangle is 10 feet long. If the altitude is decreasing at a rate of 2
inches per second, at what rate is the base angle changing when the height is 12 feet?

So far I am confused as to what I should be finding the derivative of and what values I should plug in afterwards.

Comment: thanks to calc every time i see a ladder i think of related rates

Answer (score 1):

**Draw the picture.**  You'll see a right triangle with an "adjacent" side that is $5$ feet long (half of the base) and a varying height $x$, which is the "opposite" side. Let $\theta$ be the "base angle", so that
$$
\tan\theta = \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}} = \frac x 5.
$$
Then
$$
\theta = \arctan \frac x 5.
$$
You need
$$
\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{d\theta}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}
$$
at a time when $x=12$ and $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\left( -\dfrac 2 {12} \text{ feet per second} \right) = (-2 \text{ inches per second}).$

Comment: Shouldn't it be specified that the base length will remain constant or not? Beacuse, i believe the answer would be different if it would have been the case where...the altitude is shrinking as an effect,  but given that the pair of equal sides of the isoscales triangle both being fixed in length, and if only the angles and the length of base were changing

Answer (score 0):

Let's say height is $h$ and base is $b$.
Then the base angle is 
$$\tan \theta = \frac{h}{b/2}$$

so the function you're looking for is 
$$\theta_b (h)=\tan^{-1} \frac{h}{b/2}$$
and it's derivative reads
$$\theta_b'(h)=\frac {2b}{b^2+4h^2}$$

Now you can plug in your values for $h $ and $b $.